# Rails 5: Bootstrap not styled properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am just starting to use bootstrap (I mostly work back-end) and I am a bit confused. I have configured it properly (followed every step of their [guide](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) for the bootstrap-gem setup) but when I copy the code for a navbar, [from the examples at their site](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), it is not styled at all (other than positioning).

Please, tell me what code should I provide because I am really out of my league here.

Thank you

My `application.js`

```
//= require jquery3
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

This is added to my `Gemfile`

```
gem 'bootstrap', git: 'https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sprockets-rails'
```

in my `application.html.erb`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to 'Home', movies_path %>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
        Logged in as <strong><%= current_user.email %></strong>.
        <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %> |
        <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'navbar-link' %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %> |
        <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and it's `head` is

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Finally in my `application.scss`

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: ok can you upload your code so we can check which one that not styled properly

Comment: What code do you want to see? I said in my question, I don't know what code to provide for this.

Comment: Do you get any errors in yor browser console?

Comment: No errors, the scss file contains only `@import "bootstrap";
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just to mark this as solved. This is actually a bootstrap problem, I asked on GitHub and others are facing the same problem with me. Thank you for your time and comments :)

Answer (score 0):

make sure in application.html.erb  tag you have responsive tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

below is sample of menu for twitter bootstrap with responsive menu (inside your application.html.erb) --> I custom the menu as your menu

```
  <div id="header" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- menu for mobile -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-megadropdown-tabs">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <%= link_to 'Home', movies_path %>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-megadropdown-tabs">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">MENU <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path %></li>               
                <li><%= link_to "Other menu",  %></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li> <%= link_to "LOG OUT ( #{current_user.username} )", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
         <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %></li>
        <% end %>  
        </ul> <!-- navbar-right  -->
      </div><!-- end navbar-collapse -->
    </div> <!-- end fluid -->
  </div> <!-- end navbar -->
```

Ok for styled properly you have to import css that provided, below I gave you info

inside app/stylesheets/  edit your  application.scss
and add this lines below

```
// bootstrap
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: This is functional but, not styled at all. I mean it, really, it's plain html.

Comment: I just edit and add how you can import bootstrap-sprockets (stylesheet) that provided from bootstrap, if it's still not work, then make sure you have restart the server

Comment: This is not working. Also, you didn't read my original post, I imported `bootstrap` into my `scss` file but `bootstrap-sprockets` cannot be imported anymore.